# IOS Navigation Bar always empty

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am new to IOS and Objective C development. I was trying to load JSON from web and parse it into a multilevel menu kind of thing. On clicking next button, user will be directed to another screen.
I currently have basic app in which data is loaded into class RootViewController : UITableViewController.
I want to show Navigation Bar on top of it, Which will contain next screen button.
I have tried lot of options but in everyone nothing was displayed in navigation Bar ( Navigation bar itself was there, but without title or any button). I have basic XIB in which there is only tableview under Objects.

Any pointers how can i do it.

Sample Code ( RootViewController.m) :-

```
(void)viewDidLoad

{

  DBGS;

  [super viewDidLoad];

//This Failed   self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.navigationController.editButtonItem; 
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title=@"My Title";


//This Also Failed

UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"left" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title=@"My Title";
[_backButton release];

//Remaining Code

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contents" ofType:@"json"];

self.model = [[TreeListModel alloc] initWithJSONFilePath:filePath];

}
```

Header File (RootViewController.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "TreeListModel.h"

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {

    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) TreeListModel *model;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

I am unable to post app image. But in o/p screen tableview is there(populated correctly) + A blue NavBar(No title or Button).

Thanks

Comment: How do you setup your `window` and `self.navigation` controller ? I have a doubt you have missed something. Since no need to declare `navigationController` in `RootViewcontroller`

Answer (score 2):

This code looks incomplete but it looks like you are misusing navigation controllers a bit.

[Read up on UINavigationControllers here in the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Several problems here:

1. View controllers do not need to maintain an extra reference to their navigation controller. When a view controller is added onto a navigation stack, its `navigationController` property is automatically set and controlled by the navigation controller.
2. You are setting the attributes of the navigation controller directly to style the navigation bar for a particular view controller, which won't actually do anything. You need to style the `navigationItem` of each view controller separately, and the navigation controller will automatically use those properties to create the actual navigation view.
   Change all the code that modifies the `navigationItem` to not include `navigationController`.

So like this:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
self.navigationItem.title=@"My Title";
```

edit:
And to add, because it is likely you may be confused about how to use `backBarButtonItem`. It does not represent the back button you will see on the item you are adding it to, but instead the back button you will see to go back to that current item if you push something else onto the stack.
Snippet from docs:

> When this navigation item is immediately below the top item in the
>   stack, the navigation controller derives the back button for the
>   navigation bar from this navigation item. When this property is nil,
>   the navigation item uses the value in its title property to create an
>   appropriate back button. If you want to specify a custom image or
>   title for the back button, you can assign a custom bar button item
>   (with your custom title or image) to this property instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you do the [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343) tutorial to get a feel for making iOS apps.
That said, I recommend that you implement the first screen with a navigation controller (with a title, but no buttons) and a menu. Clicking an item in the menu takes you to the second screen where you show details of the item chosen.

You can download a sample project that I made [here](https://github.com/guarani/SimpleUINavigationControllerDemo.git) which does basically what you want.

Important: Setting the navigation bar title is simply done by using

```
self.title = @"My title";
```